# How to use SVG image in Power BI visuals

Tags: svg, powerbi

I downloaded the SVG file, edited it for import into Power BI.
Next, I created a measure and entered the SVG file code there via a variable.
But for some reason, the color fill cannot bind to the measures, as a result of which the SVG does not respond to changes.
The file is located in Github:
[power bi file](https://github.com/Xazratxon/PowerBI_SVG/blob/4538c74f09896de91263cf385d838f13aed3d2ab/smoke_and_drink.pbix)

Please look at the links to the measures where I incorrectly specify the path.
Here is my code:

```
SVG_smoked = 
VAR percentArea = 'Measures_1'[Smoked] //for calculate heigth of back figure
VAR fillColor = "#ff0000" // color of useful figure
VAR backColor = "#cccccc" // color of background figure

VAR smoke_icon = 
"
data:image/svg+xml; utf8,

<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 426.667 426.667'>

<defs>
    <clipPath id='maskClip'>
        <rect x='0' y='0' width='426.667' height = '"&426.667 * (1-percentArea)&"' />
    </clipPath>
</defs>

<g style= 'fill: "&fillColor&";'>
    <path d='M299.307,206.827h-32.64v0.107c-21.76,0-39.467-20.907-39.467-42.667c0-21.76,17.707-37.333,39.467-37.333v-32
        c-39.36,0-71.467,32-71.467,71.467s32,71.467,71.467,71.467v-0.107h32.64c22.293,0,42.027,15.787,42.027,43.84v27.733h32V274.24
        C373.333,235.84,339.2,206.827,299.307,206.827z'/>
    <rect x='341.333' y='330.667' width='32' height='64'/>
    <rect x='0' y='330.667' width='320' height='64'/>
    <path d='M359.467,154.24c13.12-12.907,21.333-30.933,21.333-50.773C380.8,64,348.693,32,309.333,32v32
        c21.76,0,39.467,17.707,39.467,39.467c0,21.76-17.707,39.467-39.467,39.467v32c47.893,0,85.333,38.933,85.333,86.827v47.573h32
        v-47.68C426.667,214.187,399.36,173.227,359.467,154.24z'/>
    <rect x='394.667' y='330.667' width='32' height='64'/>
</g>


<g style= 'fill: "&backColor&"; clip-path:url(#maskClip)'>
    <path d='M299.307,206.827h-32.64v0.107c-21.76,0-39.467-20.907-39.467-42.667c0-21.76,17.707-37.333,39.467-37.333v-32
        c-39.36,0-71.467,32-71.467,71.467s32,71.467,71.467,71.467v-0.107h32.64c22.293,0,42.027,15.787,42.027,43.84v27.733h32V274.24
        C373.333,235.84,339.2,206.827,299.307,206.827z'/>
    <rect x='341.333' y='330.667' width='32' height='64'/>
    <rect x='0' y='330.667' width='320' height='64'/>
    <path d='M359.467,154.24c13.12-12.907,21.333-30.933,21.333-50.773C380.8,64,348.693,32,309.333,32v32
        c21.76,0,39.467,17.707,39.467,39.467c0,21.76-17.707,39.467-39.467,39.467v32c47.893,0,85.333,38.933,85.333,86.827v47.573h32
        v-47.68C426.667,214.187,399.36,173.227,359.467,154.24z'/>
    <rect x='394.667' y='330.667' width='32' height='64'/>
</g>
</svg>

"
return smoke_icon
```

Comment: If you simply create this svg without all the dynamic portion and with static values, does it render in a browser as you desire? Please test that and then you can probably use that to compare the DAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's it, I've solved the problem. It turns out that it is necessary to round the values in the variable "percentArea" to 2 characters
VAR percentArea =round('Measures_1'[Smoked], 2)